# how to truncate a string array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, fgets

I'm using fgets() to take input for char name[MAX_LENGTH]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 5;

int main()
{
    char name[MAX_LENGTH];
    fgets(name, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
 
    if(strlen(name) >= MAX_LENGTH)
    {
        name[MAX_LENGTH] = '\0';
    }
}
```

If the user enters `"Samuel"`, I want the program to save the leters `"Samue"` and ignore the rest. Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: `strlen("Samuel") and assign last character to be '\0'`?

Comment: A string in C contains a terminating \0, so to get "Samue" you need to set MAX_LENGTH to 6. Then the code works without the `if` -- `fgets` is defined to read at most n-1 characters.